# Forward album from 1 channel to 2 chanell

Tags: python, telethon

I found how to transfer albums from one channel to another, but how to do it in reverse, from old to new? I have all albums forwarded except for the last one

This is a working code:

```
current_album = None
current_group_id = None

async for message in client.iter_messages(test_channel_id):
    if current_group_id and message.grouped_id != current_group_id:
        print('Group finished:', current_group_id, 'had', len(current_album))
        current_group_id = None
        current_album = None

    if not current_group_id and message.grouped_id:
        print('New group:', message.grouped_id)
        current_group_id = message.grouped_id
        current_album = []

    if current_group_id:
        current_album.append(message)
```

But if I receive messages in reverse, the last album is not sent:

```
current_album = None
current_group_id = None

async for message in client.iter_messages(test_channel_id, reverse=True):
    if current_group_id and message.grouped_id != current_group_id:
        print('Group finished:', current_group_id, 'had', len(current_album))
        current_group_id = None
        current_album = None

    if not current_group_id and message.grouped_id:
        print('New group:', message.grouped_id)
        current_group_id = message.grouped_id
        current_album = []

    if current_group_id:
        current_album.append(message)
```